# Is there any OpenCV wrapper for Monotouch?

Tags: .net, opencv, xamarin.ios

OpenCV (Open Source Computer Vision) is a library of programming
functions for real time computer vision and augmented reality.

http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/

I've only found a couple of iOS ports:

https://github.com/macmade/OpenCV-iOS

https://github.com/BloodAxe/opencv-ios-template-project

And a specific iOS folder and makefile in the official repository:

https://code.ros.org/svn/opencv/trunk/opencv/ios/

Is there any OpenCV C# wrapper for Monotouch?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Not quite sure about Monotouch but [EmguCV](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) is a wrapper for C#/.Net. 
Since Monotouch declares .Net libraries compability is should suit to your needs.

Comment: The above link has a table comparing it (EmguCV) to other OpenCV bindings for .NET. More choice is a click away :-)

Comment: Unfortunately I've checked it all, but there are no MonoTouch builds. Mono is a very different platform from MonoTouch, and some DLLs required by those Distributions are not awailable. In addition other wrappers such as OpenCVDotNet, SharperCV or Code Project use unsafe code not compatible with MonoTouch on iPhone. The only one that doesn't use it is EmguCV, written entirely in managed C#, but it still requires some DLLs from Mono not available in MonoTouch. No wonder none of those sites even mention MonoTouch on their pages. :(

Comment: @EmanueleSabetta yes, there is no MonoTouch builds (cause it is too specifical), but why don't you make one? Source code of EmguCV (and the others too) is [available](http://sourceforge.net/scm/?type=svn&group_id=216500).

Comment: As of mid-2012 they're claiming it's compatible with MonoTouch.